# how to delete Glide cache using Admad cakephp-glide in cakephp4?

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I'm using the plugin cakephp-glide in my Cakephp4 App.

I want to delete Glide cache of an image just after the image is deleted.

My plugin `FileManager` triggers an event 'afterDelete' when the image file is deleted :

```
// in FileManager.FichiersTable
public function afterDelete(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
    $fichier = new File(WWW_ROOT . $entity->url);
    $fichier->delete();

    $afterDeleteEvent = new Event('FileManager.Fichiers.afterDelete', $this, [
        'file' => $entity
    ]);
    $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($afterDeleteEvent);
}
```

and I want to catch the event in bootstrap of my application to delete the cache of the image :

```
//in bootstrap.php
EventManager::instance()
    ->on(
        'FileManager.Fichiers.afterDelete',
        function (Event $event) {
            // Delete cache of $event->getData('file')
            $filename = $event->getData('file')->filename;
            $server->deleteCache($filename); // How to get the instance $server ???
        }
    );
```

But I don't know how to get the Glide Server instance ?

I can't find a method in the plugin to get it.
If someone could help me...

Comment: Looking at the plugin code, the server instance seems to never leave the middleware, and it's not even created for every request. I have no idea if instantiating the server yourself is a good idea, I've never used Glide, so I can't really give any further advice. You may want to ask this question over in Slack, where ADmad is around sometimes too, or maybe even create an issue over at GitHub if you think this is something that could be considered missing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ADmad advices, the solution is to store the Glide server config in `Configure` and then use this config both in routes for the ADmad/Glide plugin configuration and in my event listener to create a new server instance.

```
//in bootstrap.php
//'ADmad/Glide.server' will be used in routes to configure the plugin and in my event listener below to create a new server instance.
Configure::write('ADmad/Glide.server', [
            // Path or League\Flysystem adapter instance to read images from.
            // http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/source-and-cache/
            'source' => WWW_ROOT,

            // Path or League\Flysystem adapter instance to write cached images to.
            'cache' => WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'cache',

            // URL part to be omitted from source path. Defaults to "/images/"
            // http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/source-and-cache/#set-a-base-url
            'base_url' => '/images/',

            // Response class for serving images. If unset (default) an instance of
            // \ADmad\Glide\Response\PsrResponseFactory() will be used.
            // http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/responses/
            'response' => null,
        ]);

EventManager::instance()
    ->on(
        'FileManager.Fichiers.afterDelete',
        function (Event $event) {
            $server = \League\Glide\ServerFactory::create(Configure::read('ADmad/Glide.server')); // Use the Glide server config above
            $file = $event->getData('file');
            $server->deleteCache(Configure::read('ADmad/Glide.server.base_url') . $file->url);

        }
    );
    }
);
```